# deleting TXMLDocument object Embarcadero

Tags: c++, c++builder, delete-operator, txmldocument

I've got an object to delete:

```
XMLDoc = new TXMLDocument(NULL);
```

but I have no idea how to do that... it's not working:

```
delete XMLDoc;
XMLDoc->free();
```

When I try just delete object the program crashes.

So it's a piece of my code. I've got a class:

```
class C_XMLhandler{
    private:
        TXMLDocument *XMLDoc;
...
...
    public:
        void loadXMLfile(String name);
...
...
};

and example declaration of method:
bool C_XMLhandler::loadXMLfile(String name)
{
        XMLDoc = new TXMLDocument(NULL);
        Box=GetMagicBox(XMLDoc); //it's XML parser method, and it's doesen't matter
        delete XMLDoc; //when i reach this line the program scrashes
}
```

Comment: And `XMLDoc` is not deleted in `GetMagicBox`?

Comment: no - and if i don't delete this object i've got some memory leak. It's not big, but always is :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.Destroy

The object is deleted by the component it is connected to new (this) otherwise not really sure, I read somewhere that it is auto deleted. (hmmm)

Comment: Please refrain from giving **link-only** answers as they are worthless if the link is down.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you `delete` the object before calling the `free` method in the now deleted object.

When you do `delete XMLDoc` the memory allocated for `XMLDoc` is marked as free, and the object destructor is executed. Now when using the pointer in calling `XMLDoc->free()` you are accessing memory that is no longer allocated, and you experience *undefined behavior*, which some times leads to a crash.

You should first check if the `free` method is not called inside the object destructor, and if it isn't then do it the other way around. *If* `free` is called in the destructor, you don't need to call it at all.

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstand me. I meat that i can't delete this object - XMLDoc. I can't get throught line delete XMLDoc, because program crashes without any information, debugging is also not helping. 
I tried use
delete XMLDoc and XMLDoc->free()
separately

Comment: @user2401015 Then the pointer is overwritten somewhere. Set a breakpoint when you allocate the object, and write down the resulting pointer address. If it's different when you try to delete the pointer then you overwrite it somewhere.

Comment: @user2401015 If the debugger is good enough, you should be able to add a watch on `XMLDoc`, and then the debugger will break if it changes. Then you will find out where your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but it's not the clue. I've met with such situation first time, that i can't delete object. I add some code up^^.

Answer (score 0):

Got your solution.  Ran into this today myself. I fully understand. You have a library, creating a TXMLDocument object on the fly and tossing when you are finished, yet application "tosses cookies" instead, exceptions for invalid pointer operation.
Solution, give it an owner that handles the release, and free the owner (TComponent).

Delphi code, all the same concept.

```
procedure PlayWithDocument();
var
 owner: TComponent;
 doc: TXMLDocument;
begin
  owner := TComponent.Create(nil);
  try
    doc := TXMLDocument.Create(owner);
    // play with doc to your hearts content.
  finally
    // freeing owner, TXMLDocument.  
    // TODO: Check for memory leaks (I suspect none).
    FreeAndNil(owner);
  end;
end;
```